# Let's Encrypt with ASP.NET Core in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, lets-encrypt, azure-keyvault

I am going to host ASP.NET Core application in Azure Service Fabric, and I would like to use Let's Encrypt certificate authority to generate and renew SSL certificates.

I am trying to store the certificate in Azure Key Vault, read it on a service startup and pass it right into Kestrel web server's configuration. Decided to use Azure Key Vault because service could run on any VM in cluster, moreover cluster (Virtual machine scale set) could have an auto scale.

My question are there any approaches to generate Let's Encrypt certificates and auto-renew then in future?

Comment: there is a bunch of scripts\modules lying around in the web to do that, none of them put certificate into Azure Key Vault to my knowledge

Comment: Scott Hanselman had a blog post recently about I think a marketplace plugin that does auto-renewal of Let’s Encrypt certs, that might be worth looking up.

Comment: @Matt that was specific to azure web apps.